# c++11 thread or boost.thread support android ios

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, boost, c++11

My question is very simple. I need to make use of threads on a game that will be running in android and iOS as the main platforms. I am using xcode 5 in Mac OSX 10.9 for development.

1. Can I use c++11 threads?
2. Can I use boost.thread, if c++11 threads are not ready?
3. Otherwise, which are the alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just did a test with XCode 5.1 IOS7.1.

- Create new Empty project
- Rename AppDelegate.m -> AppDelegate.mm
- #include <thread>
- Ran the following code:

`std::thread t([]() {
     NSLog(@"thread function");
});`

Worked.

## Android

Same code runs in Android NDK r8e using GCC 4.7 (which is what I'm using atm).  I updated to 9d and using GCC 4.8 it still works.

Comment: This helps to illustrate how a lot of the time you should just create a test project. Most developers really try to avoid it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer about android ndk.

1. There is gcc 4.8 in lastest adnroid NDK. It seems promised, but I did not try it.
2. You can. I used boost.thread at last project and it works perfect.
3. posix threads

About IOS, I exactly know, that you can use boost. I worked with android project, that was port from IOS. There was a lot of boost in IOS version. And I think Xcode 5 must have good support of C++11, just write some test.